# Displaying a list of string in a string

Tags: c#, string, counter

Ok I am here trying to to send out an email to user regarding invalid attachments.  I am collecting a list of invalid attachments name (string) in a previous function and then I am trying to send an email which would list all the attachments which were deemed invalid.  not sure how to approach this situation.  I have the following example

```
List<string> invalidType = new List<string>();

if (invalidType != null)
{
    emailInvalidBody = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = " Expense attachements recieved with subject line [ "
           + email.Subject 
           + " ] sent at  [  " 
           + email.DateTimeReceived.Value.DateTime.ToLocalTime() 
           + " ] had the following invalid attachments [" 
           + invalidType 
           + "].  Please make sure all attachment's are images or PDF's.",
    };
}
List<Recipient> emailInvalidRecipients = new List<Recipient>();
emailInvalidRecipients.Add(new Recipient
{
    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
    {
        Address = email.Sender.EmailAddress.Address
    }
});
Message invalidEmailMessage = new Message
{
    Subject = "Invalid Expenses",
    Body = emailInvalidBody,
    ToRecipients = emailInvalidRecipients
};
starBox.Users[EMAILBOX].SendMailAsync(invalidEmailMessage, false).Wait();
```

My ultimate goal is to have an email body that will do the following

> "Expense attachements recieved with subject line Subject sent at 8:00 1/29/16 had the following invalid attachments [ invalidattachment1 invalidattachment2 invalidattachment3 invalidattachment4 ].  Please make sure all attachment's are images or PDF's.",

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `@` before some of the strings you concatenate together and assign to `Content`, that or it should all be on one line maybe?

Comment: for completeness (and to avoid an unneeded and odd-looking email) you should also check for invalidType.Any() after you check for != null;    bonus: non-programming observation: you misspelled "attachments" and "received"

Comment: haha thank you, writting this on the fly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use string.Join to trasform your `List<string>` in a list with all the items joined together

```
List<string> invalidType = new List<string>();
.....

// Probably you don't need to check for null but for element count.
// However it doesn't hurt to be a little defensive...
if (invalidType != null && invalidType.Count > 0)
{
    string attachments = string.join(",", invalidType);
    emailInvalidBody = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = " Expense attachments received with subject line [ " + 
                  email.Subject + " ] sent at  [  " + 
                  email.DateTimeReceived.Value.DateTime.ToLocalTime() + 
                  " ]  had the following invalid attachments [" + 
                  attachments + "].  Please make sure all " + 
                  " attachment's are images or PDF's.",
    };

}
```

Comment: this is more efficient than `Ling` and the `Aggregate()` method. 
+1 (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linq` `Aggregate`

```
Content = " Expense attachements recieved with subject line [ " +
 email.Subject + " ] sent at  [  " + 
email.DateTimeReceived.Value.DateTime.ToLocalTime() + 
" ]had the following invalid attachments [" 
+ invalidType.Aggregate((i, j) => i + " " + j))
+ "].  Please make sure all attachment's are images or PDF's.",
```

Comment: true, but the intent isn't as clear as with string.Join()